# HTTPError when using urllib.request.urlopen() on known available url

Tags: http, python-3.x

I have some very simple python code that tries to get the HTML of a webpage.

```
import urllib

url = 'https://www.____.com'     # A URL that works in my browser
u = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

I then use `u` to find a link on the web page and download a file.

I have been using this code for a few days without problem, but now I receive an `HTTPError 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable` when I try to open the URL. I don't really know much about this sort of stuff, but I assume the website figured out a robot was repeatedly trying to gain access and somehow blocked it.

How might I go about fixing this? Is there a more website-friendly way to retrieve data?

Answer (score 0):

According to [pictuga's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17391477/1335264), the problem may be that the default [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Crawler_identification) specified by urllib.request.urlopen is banned by the website to prevent web crawlers from accessing the site. You may be able to get around this restriction by setting a custom user agent when you open your request, as indicated in the Python 3.3 documentation for [`urllib.request.Request`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request):

> headers should be a dictionary, and will be treated as if add_header()
>   was called with each key and value as arguments. This is often used to
>   “spoof” the User-Agent header, which is used by a browser to identify
>   itself – some HTTP servers only allow requests coming from common
>   browsers as opposed to scripts. For example, Mozilla Firefox may
>   identify itself as "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127
>   Firefox/2.0.0.11", while urllib‘s default user agent string is
>   "Python-urllib/2.6" (on Python 2.6).

In other words, you should create a `Request` object by passing a custom user agent to `urllib.request.Request` as part of the `headers` dictionary (with key `"User-Agent"`). You can then call `urllib.request.urlopen` on that request to get the (hopefully-successful) response. For code showing this approach go check out [Oleh Prypin's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10946539/1335264).